# How to avoid variable substitution in Perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl, variable-substitution

I have the following regex:

```
my ($pkg) = ( $xmldirname =~ /$db(.*)^/ );
```

What it should do is: check if the xmldirname starts ($) with "db" and take the rest of the string into $pkg.

What it does is: "Global symbol $db requires explicit package name".

How do I do this? Using qr// didn't work, either.

Yes, ok, I see. $ is end, not start. I'm sorry....

Comment: Can someone close or delete this? The question was wrong from the start, and any answer is just a waste of time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you misused the anchor.

> What it should do is: check if the xmldirname starts ($) with "db" and take the rest of the string into $pkg.

Use this:

```
my ($pkg) = ( $xmldirname =~ /^db(.*)$/ );
```

You could also remove the terminal `$`:

```
my ($pkg) = ( $xmldirname =~ /^db(.*)/ );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can escape `$` using backslash (`\`) so that it loses its special meaning:

```
my ($pkg) = ( $xmldirname =~ /\$db(.*)^/ );
```

Alternatively, you can specify arbitrary delimiter for `m` (in fact, any quote-like operator) operator, and using single quote (`'`) disables string interpolation:

```
my ($pkg) = ( $xmldirname =~ m'$db(.*)^' );
```

See [Quote and Quote-like Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators)

Comment: Embarrasingly simply... thx. Seems I thought the \ was only relevant to literals for the regex-engine itself.

Comment: Just that I used "$" for start of line, when it should be ^ ... so this question should be cancelled.

Answer (score 1):

- You can escape the `$`
- Add the anchor `^` at the begining of the regex and not at the end

The code can be

```
my ($pkg) = ( $xmldirname =~ /^\$db(.*)/ );
```

**Test**

```
$xmldirname = '$dbhello';
my ($pkg) = ( $xmldirname =~ /^\$db(.*)/ );
print $pkg;
```

will give output as

```
hello
```